# best way to layout controls for a form

Tags: android, user-interface, tablelayout

I am building an input form  for 10" tablet with android UI in landscape mode.

Main layout is TableLayout because there are many input data elements.

What will be best way to layout like 6 sets of text view and text edit in the same row:

```
 [FName]___________[MName]___________[LName]___________[Age]_____ [date of birth]___________
```

Is it possible to use GridLayout in a TableRow?

 When I do use it, I get a warning:

```
This GridLayout layout or its TableRow parent is useless
```

When I use only TableRow I struggle with the text width's

Comment: Is there only one row?

Comment: There are multiple rows, but I would like to have these 6 controls on the same row.

Comment: you can use **LinearLayout** and maintain all 6 fields using **layout_weight**.

Comment: if you have multiple rows you can also use **TableLayout**